# Ajuda - C++ Ler Arquivo e substi

Tags: dev-c++

Boa noite pessoal
estou com uma dúvida em c++
preciso ler um arquivo e substituir alguns caracteres por outro e gerar um novo arquivo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/substituir-uma-sequencia-de-caracteres-em-c/505368 Isto te ajudaria?

Comment: Sim. Para isso, vá em [edit] e refaça sua pergunta colocando o código que já fez até agora, descreva as dificuldades encontradas, os erros que deram, liste aquilo que ainda falta fazer, descreva os resultados obtidos até agora, os resultados desejados e faça uma comparação entre ambos. Busque também elaborar um [mcve], ler o guia de [ask] e fazer o [tour] para aprender melhor o funcionamento do site. Se restar alguma dúvida, acesse a [help] e o [meta].

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isto ajuda.. (testado no onlinegdb)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <sstream> //std::stringstream
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// CRIO O ARQUIVO 
std::ofstream outfile ("test.txt");

outfile << "conteudo do arquivo!" << std::endl;

outfile.close();
//FIM DA CRIACAO DO ARQUIVO

//ABRE ARQUIVO
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("test.txt"); //open the input file

std::stringstream strStream;
strStream << inFile.rdbuf(); //read the file
std::string str = strStream.str(); //str holds the content of the file

std::cout << str; //you can do anything with the string!!!

std::string s = str;
boost::replace_all(s, "arquivo", "ficha"); // REPLACE -> SUBSTITUI
//std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'arquivo', 'ficha'); // replace all 'x' to 'y'

std::cout << s;
return 0;
}
```

teste do codigo
https://onlinegdb.com/B1vCwLOOV